# how to generate unique id (MC0001) in database using php and it wont repeat in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried doing the code but the the output I am getting is same id again and again in database MC00001.

```
$value2='';
    //Query to fetch last inserted invoice number
    $query1 = "SELECT uniqueuserid from registration order by uniqueuserid DESC LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $con->query($query1);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            $value2 = $row['uniqueuserid'];
            $value2 = substr($value2, 10, 13);//separating numeric part
            $value2 = $value2 + 1;//Incrementing numeric part
            $value2 = "MC" . sprintf('%03s', $value2);//concatenating incremented value
            $value = $value2; 
        }
    } 
    else {
        $value2 = "MC00001";
        $value = $value2;
    }
```

Actual: MC00001,MC00001,MC00001,

Expected : MC00001,MC00002,MC000003

Comment: Please wrap your code with ```, it is hardly readable now

Comment: Why not just use an ordinary auto-increment integer in your database and format it via `sprintf('MC%05d', $id)` when required? You can even reverse it to get the ID via `[ $id ] = sscanf($str, 'MC%05d)`

Comment: @Phil auto increments in mysql can have gaps in them, e.g., 1,2,5,6. OP doesnt specify, but it might not be what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$id = 'MC00001';
list($idString, $idNumber) = sscanf($id,"%[A-Za-z]%[0-9]");
echo $idString.str_pad($idNumber + 1,6,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```